# URL design for city landing page: /chicago or /?_city=chicago

Tags: seo, url-design

I am interested on thoughts about URL structure for city landing pages.

Essentially best practice and reasons for implementing format (a) over (b):

(a) `example.com/chicago`
(b) `example.com/?_city=chicago`

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [Is a URL with a query string better or worse for SEO then one without one?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15393/is-a-url-with-a-query-string-better-or-worse-for-seo-then-one-without-one)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the path instead of the query component is typically considered to be more user-friendly. So go with *(a)*:

```
/chicago
```

If you want to represent (in the URL) that it’s about cities (what *(b)* does), you can do this in the path, too:

```
/cities/chicago
```

This allows you to provide [browsable URLs](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55739/17633), i.e., offering a list of all cities at:

```
/cities
```